# ACL mask does not work as expected

Tags: permissions, cp, acl

If I copy a file with a base ACL of:

```
u::rw-,g::r--,o::r--
```

into a directory with a default ACL of:

```
u::rwx,g::r-x,g:users:rwx,m::rwx,o::r-x
```

I obtain a file with mask of `m::r--`. I would have expected the union of the permissions of the two group entries (i.e. `m::rwx`).

Why it is so? Does it depend on the `mode` parameter used by `cp` in the creation of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume you're working on Linux, the workings of ACLs differ between unix variants.)

`cp` doesn't do anything special when you copy the file; it creates the file with the mode of the original file, masked by the mask of the directory. Since `cp` doesn't do anything to the file's mask, the mask ends up being the *intersection* of the directory mask (`rwx`) and the file's group permissions (`r`).

```
open("dir/file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644)
```

Comment: When one has set the default ACL (which is passed on to newly created subfolders), how does the mask + default acl + folder perms get fused together, when a new subfolder is created???

Comment: @nass The default ACL is used if no ACL has been set explicitly. If there's an explicit ACL then its mask is used, otherwise the default mask is used.

Comment: I am abit fuzzy about the mask acl. if I set an explicit acl to a folder, I expect this to be followed. you tell me that regardless of my explicit acl, the actual perms will be the intersection of the mask with the acl? and when I set a default acl then that is taken as is (ie without intersection with the mask acl?) may I also refer you to a question I have here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85633/copying-a-file-on-a-jfs-filesystem-does-not-follow-acl-guidelines/85648?noredirect=1#85648