# Copying a file on a JFS filesystem, does not follow ACL guidelines

Tags: filesystems, acl, jfs

I have a JFS filesystem

```
/dev/md2 on /mnt/hd2 type jfs (rw)
```

to which I'm trying to copy some folders into target folder `/mnt/hd2/videos/movies/`.

NOTE: I'm actually not using this target folder directly, but a symbolic link in my home folder that points to the target folder.

Now, the folder `/mnt/hd2/videos/movies/` has default group ACL enabled:

```
nass@stargaze:/mnt/hd2/videos$ getfacl Movies/
# file: Movies/
# owner: nass
# group: shares
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:shares:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

I copied the folders from a temporary folder and expected to get the group write permission to be set as well, instead the folder looks like this:

```
drwxr-sr-x+ 2 nass shares        24 Aug  6 01:12 The_Movie/
```

I had set ACLs on the "videos" folder initially, and all the sub-folders have inherited the default from that top folder.

What have I missed?

EDIT: JFS ACL support is indeed compiled in the kernel.

EDIT2: getfacl on `The_Movie/` looks like

```
nass@stargaze:/mnt/hd2/videos/Movies$ getfacl The_Movie/
# file: The_Movie/
# owner: nass
# group: shares
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx                      #effective:r-x
group:shares:rwx                #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:shares:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

the source folder is on another jfs disk. the folder was transferred to that source location through a cifs share and, i think it was given initial permissions 755.

Comment: Are you copying from one type of FS to another? (For example ext4 files -> JFS)? Also the `+` in the output means that ACL's are set on the `The_Movie/` dir. Can you do a getfacl of that dir and provide output?

Comment: @slm hi there, i updated the question to provide feedback

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Kernel is compiled with support for JFS & ACLs. You can check like so:

```
$ zgrep CONFIG_JFS_POSIX_ACL /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_JFS_POSIX_ACL=y
```

Comment: it is compiled with support for ACLs...